# How to ignore dev dependencies in WhiteSource scan for nuget packages

Tags: security, nuget, nuget-package

I want to ignore my **SonarAnalyzer.Csharp** and **Sonarlint** package in the C# code WhiteSource scan. They are being captured as Policy Violation.

I checked the documentation, there is no option to ignore checking dev dependencies 
https://whitesource.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/WD/pages/489160834/Unified+Agent+Configuration+File+Parameters.

Is there any option that we can provide in the WhiteSource config file to skip it. My packages.config file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" version="1.21.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="SonarLint" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the WhiteSource Unified Agent Configuration, there is a section where you can exclude file extensions or specific directories - it is under the Includes/Excludes Glob patterns.

Comment: Downvoted because you didnt actually respond to the question. I am also interested in this topic and your answer is not helping.

Comment: downvoted as well because it does not answer the question at all.

Comment: downvoted, does not ignore dev dependencies and also missing an example and Atlasssian docs are as ever terrible

Comment: downvoted, this answer is not an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [White Source Unified Agent Configuration](https://docs.mend.io/bundle/unified_agent/page/unified_agent_configuration_parameters.html) for details of how to setup glob patterns.

As an example you might start with the defaults

```
#########################################################################################
# Includes/Excludes Glob patterns - PLEASE USE ONLY ONE EXCLUDE LINE AND ONE INCLUDE LINE
#########################################################################################

#includes=**/*.c **/*.cc **/*.cp **/*.cpp **/*.cxx **/*.c++ **/*.h **/*.hpp **/*.hxx
#includes=**/*.m **/*.mm  **/*.js **/*.php
#includes=**/*.jar
#includes=**/*.gem **/*.rb
#includes=**/*.dll **/*.cs **/*.nupkg
#includes=**/*.tgz **/*.deb **/*.gzip **/*.rpm **/*.tar.bz2
#includes=**/*.zip **/*.tar.gz **/*.egg **/*.whl **/*.py
   
## Exclude file extensions or specific directories by adding **/*.<extension> or **<excluded_dir>/**
excludes=**/*sources.jar **/*javadoc.jar
```

You can add more patterns, and its suggested that all your patterns are held on one line.

The example here shows you how to exclude two types of file - you could update the pattern to match the files you wish to exclude.